# Can't access localhost with wamp and Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, localhost, wamp

from today, when I go to localhost (http://localhost) after launch WAMP, in Firefox, as usual, everything is normal, but Chrome says "Forbidden, You don't have permission to access / on this server."

Anyone can help me please ?

Comment: is there anything in your htdocs root?

Comment: When you acces the wamp menu in the system tray, does it say "Put Online" or "Put Offline"?

Comment: @TZHX : where is this file ?

Comment: @Rendiel : what is the system tray ?

Comment: @DarkCid  it's the area of the task-bar that holds icons of running programs, usually in the lower right hand corner of the screen:

[Image for clairty](https://www.google.com/search?q=wamp+system+tray&safe=off&es_sm=122&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMIkLTV3cvoxwIVA5qICh10tg8p&biw=1920&bih=1010#imgrc=cLAI3y6uLUt6iM%3A)

Comment: @Rendiel : It's say "Put Online"

Comment: I also have this problem. Just started yesterday. It has been working for years and there have been no config file changes . Have you had any luck resolving it?

Comment: I have the same problem with XAMPP just started after last Chrome update.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Edit: Solved it for me.

This is an IPv6 problem. Google must have just updated Chrome.

First of all ensure that your hosts file has the following line and that it is uncommented.

```
::1 localhost
```

Next, open up your Apache config (httpd.conf) and add the following to the listen section:

```
Listen [::1]:80
```

Next, you need to edit you Directory statements in httpd.conf or your vhosts files. They probably look something like this.

```
<Directory "C:\path">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Add an extra line after the 'Allow from 127.0.0.1' so it looks like this

```
<Directory "C:\path">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    Allow from ::1
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone running into this problem this is what worked for me on apache 2.4.17

- host file is here: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
- httpd.conf is here: C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.17\conf
- httpd-vhosts.conf is here: C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.17\conf\extra

I made sure that localhost was enabled in my hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost
```

just remove the # at the beginning of the line.

make sure this line in un-commented in your httpd.conf

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

In my file it was line 518.

then add this to your httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin somerandomdude@whaaat.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

Then restart WAMP.

I don't know if that's the cleanest way of doing it(probs not). but it worked pretty well for me.

Answer (score 0):

It happens the same to me. From today I can not access with http://localhost to my wamp files with chrome.

In Firefox or Explorer I have no problems.

You can use 127.0.0.1 while the problem is solved.

Comment: Thanks, I can access my website with the address 127.0.0.1 but all my websites are configured with http://localhost, so I have countless errors :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This is how I solved it out:

- I first added `::1` to host file,usually found at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`
- Then I went ahead an opened my Chrome browser. I went to settings>advanced settings>Open proxy settings (under the title system)
- In the new window that pops up go to 'LAN settings' then make sure you check 'Automatically detect settings'