# WAMP server localhost wont work with Chrome

Tags: php, mysql

My WAMP server localhost only works with MS edge but doesn't with chrome.

Comment: The questions ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Chrome experiences an error connecting (please check your connection) to wamp server but edge works fine at the same time.

Comment: Wouldn't [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453984/cant-access-localhost-with-wamp-and-chrome) solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Windows 10. Tried all options found on the internet (changing port, host file config, firewall,...), but in my case it was simply **caused by Chrome's automatic redirection to http*S* protocol for localhost adress** and *Wamp by default does not support https*. So i had to remove that automatic redirect to stay on http protocol for localhost.

I made that typing "chrome://net-internals/#hsts" in the adress bar of Chrome, and enter "localhost" in the "Delete domain security policies" section, and clic on "Delete" button. In my case it helped, i hope it will help you too!