# localhost works in Edge but not in Chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome

I'm doing an on-line Java course and created a very simple server.  Using Edge as client it works but not with Chrome.  I've tried turning off firewall and some of the things suggested here ([WAMP server localhost wont work with Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48965176/wamp-server-localhost-wont-work-with-chrome#)) and elsewhere, but they all seem to be overly complicated changes to Windows files.  Surely there's a config setting somewhere?!

In Edge it's fine, in Chrome it returns this whether I use localhost:999 or 127.0.0.1:999. I've tried other ports too.

This page isn’t working
127.0.0.1 sent an invalid response.
ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE

Here is my code in case needed.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (
        ServerSocket aServer = new ServerSocket(999);
        Socket cn = aServer.accept();
         BufferedReader bis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cn.getInputStream()));
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(cn.getOutputStream());)

        {
            String line = bis.readLine();
        while(line != null && !line.equals(""))
        {
            System.out.println(line);
            line = bis.readLine();
        }

        bos.write("Hello from java TCP Server!".getBytes());

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error in connnection: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you are going to use a server from an HTTP browser, you have to return proper HTTP responses. That is, the server's first line should be a `200 OK`, followed by headers, followed by body. Edge may be lenient about this, but Chrome expects proper HTTP. If you want simple TCP/IP, don't use Chrome, but something like telnet.

Comment: Thanks.  Guess I've found a use for Edge then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web browsers require that the server speaks HTTP protocol. A proper server response would be:

```
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(System.out);

byte[] message="Hello from java TCP Server!".getBytes();

bos.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n".getBytes());
bos.write("Content-Type: text/plain\r\n".getBytes());
bos.write(("Content-Length: "+message.length+"\r\n").getBytes());
bos.write("\r\n".getBytes()); // empty line between HTTP header and HTTP content
bos.write(message);
```

You may test your program with another tool that speaks plain TCP sockets. Ich recommend "Netcat" (command: nc). Download for Windows: http://stefanfrings.de/avr_tools/netcat-win32-1.12.zip